# Initialization and declaration of variable in Constructor in java

Tags: java

In the code below i am creating and assigning the value of a in the constructor.

I know how to update the value of a.(by using a =2 instead of int a=2)

what happens to this new value of a in the program and if i have to how to i access it?

```
public class Consttest{
    int a = 12;
    Consttest(){
        int a = 2; // where is this gone?
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Consttest test = new Consttest();
        System.out.println(test.a); // a=12
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by what happens to this new value of a(2) in the program and if i have to how to i access it?

Comment: Your question seems vague or is missing essential details/code. Please look over [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Initialized variable `a` in `Consttest()` constructor is a local variable of constructor and it overrides field `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You override a variable on constructor level.
If you want to assign value to a variable just don't recreate it.

```
public class Consttest{
    int a = 12;
    Consttest(){
        this.a = 2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Consttest test = new Consttest();
        System.out.println(test.a); // a=2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create a variable inside any method. Its stay alive till method scope. when method is finished, It will be destroyed(removed from stack).

```
  public class Consttest{
        int a = 12;
        Consttest(){
            a = 2; //change this line like this.
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Consttest test = new Consttest();
            System.out.println(test.a); // a=12
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known as variable shadowing.

Variables have what's known as scope which means they can only be accessed at the level they're declared or higher.

A variable declared at the class level - fields, are available at the class level and method level.

A variable declared at the method level can only be accessed from within the method. You are free to declare variables at different levels with the same name.

A variable declared in a method that has the same name as a class level variable takes more precedence to the instance variable so the compiler uses this variable. This is shadowing

A constructor is a special kind of method.

```
public class Consttest{
    int a = 12; // instance level scope, can be 'seen' at the class level or method level
    Consttest(){
        int a = 2; // where is this gone? - this is declared at the method level which shadows the instace variable a
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Consttest test = new Consttest();
        System.out.println(test.a); // a=12
    }
}
```

When a method is called, a new stackframe is created. When the method returns this stackframe is popped off the stack and any variables created within the stackframe are dereferenced unless you pass out an object reference so in answer to the question where does it go? - It's gone.